# How to define function of multiple parameters and tuple in Python?

Tags: python, function, syntax, tuples, definition

I'm new to Python and I would like to define a function which takes 5 arguments *and* a tuple at the end.
What is the syntax for this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should put your attempts and explain why you cannot achieve it.

Comment: A tuple is simply another argument. What else is new?

Answer (score 2):

Since Python is dynamically typed, there is no way (or need) to specify the type of arguments. So if you have 5 arguments, and another argument at the end that is a tuple, then you simply have 6 arguments:

```
def example (arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5, someTuple):
    print('You passed: {}, {}, {}, {}, {}'.format(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5))
    print('And the following tuple:')
    print(someTuple)

example('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', (1, 2, 3, 4))
```

Gives the following output:

```
You passed: A, B, C, D, E
And the following tuple:
(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Comment: Thank you!
See though, I'm trying to use [[curve_fit]] on that function and I am getting a "tuple index out of range" error.

I'm doing it like so:
[[popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, x, y, p0=q)]].

Any ideas would be very much appreciated.

Comment: @nikfilippas That’s an entirely different question. If that’s what you were trying to do, you should have said so from the beginning. It’s not you who passes arguments to the function, so that really changes things. That being said, I don’t know how `curve_fit` works, so I can’t help you there.